# Entry data form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-entry

I'm creating a data entry form to a database sheet, previously I've managed to create a single cell data entry form. But now I'm going to create a data entry form that is entered in the range B6:N10. How do I modify it?

```
function SIMPAN1() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hnezkq89bgVUvimYDdAfWDVY01f7ekFN3T6TY3Ui6oA");
  var sheetInput = Sheet.getSheetByName('INPUT');
  var sheetDb = Sheet.getSheetByName('DATABASE');
  var lastRow = sheetDb.getRange("B1").getDataRegion().getLastRow();
  lastRow += 1
  var data1 = [[tgl1 = sheetInput.getRange('B6').getValue(),
  nama1 = sheetInput.getRange('C6').getValue(),
  kls1 = sheetInput.getRange('D6').getValue(),
  srthfl1 = sheetInput.getRange('E6').getValue(),
  aythfl1 = sheetInput.getRange('F6').getValue(),
  nilaithfz1 = sheetInput.getRange('G6').getValue(),
  jldsrt1 = sheetInput.getRange('H6').getValue(),
  hlmayt1 = sheetInput.getRange('I6').getValue(),
  mtri1 = sheetInput.getRange('J6').getValue(),
  nilaitrtl1 = sheetInput.getRange('K6').getValue(),
  prgst1 = sheetInput.getRange('L6').getValue(),
  prgda1 = sheetInput.getRange('M6').getValue(),
  ket1 = sheetInput.getRange('N6').getValue(),]];
  sheetDb.getRange("B" + lastRow + ":N" + lastRow).setValues(data1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function SIMPAN1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const ish = ss.getSheetByName('INPUT');
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('DATABASE');
  const ivs = ish.getRange(6, 2, 1, 13).getValues();
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 2, ivs.length, ivs[0].length).setValues(ivs);
}
```